# How do I implement variable backoff in Mono.retry?

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor

I feel like I'm missing some simple fundamental nuance but for some reason `Mono.delay()` is not working for me. I have Mono that makes http request that could be throttled. I need to wait provided time to retry. Here is how it looks now

```
internal fun <T> Mono<T>.retryAfter(maxRetries: Int, uri: URI): Mono<T> {
    // `this` is instance of Mono<T>
    return this.retryWhen(Retry.from {
        it.map { rs ->
            val ex = rs.failure()
            if (ex is RetryAfterException && rs.totalRetries() < maxRetries) {
                println("*** API throttling on call to $uri. Will wait for ${ex.delay}. Retry count: ${rs.totalRetries()}. ms ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
                Mono.delay(ex.delay.plusMillis(500), Schedulers.parallel()).then(Mono.defer({
                    println("   Waited. ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
                    this
                }))
            } else
                Mono.error(rs.failure())
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use the built-in retry builders?

Comment: looking at the code I'm a bit unclear what `this` would be in the `defer` block. I don't think `defer` is the right operator here, replace with `doOnNext` for instance.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi Delay is different on every re-try. Is there way to do it using standard builder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `map`, which results in a `Flux<Mono<?>>` being returned to the operator for retry control. from the operator's perspective (`Flux<?>`), any `onNext` means "you should retry". whether it is `onNext("example")` or `onNext(Mono.error(err))` doesn't matter.

instead of using `map`, use `concatMap`. The `Mono` that you produce in your function will correctly result in a `Flux<?>` in which the "delay" branch of the `if` produces (delayed) `onNext` while the other branch produces `onError`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use built in retry builders
I suggest you to use `Retry.fixedDelay()` which allow you to define a max retry and a delay between each try. When max retry is reached you'll get a Mono.error()

```
    internal fun <T> Mono<T>.retryAfter(maxRetries: Long, uri: URI): Mono<T> {
        // `this` is instance of Mono<T>
        return this.retryWhen(Retry.fixedDelay(maxRetries, Duration.ofMillis(500))
                .doBeforeRetry { rs: Retry.RetrySignal? -> println("Will retry " + rs?.totalRetries()) }
                .doAfterRetry{ rs: Retry.RetrySignal? -> println("Has retried " + rs?.totalRetries()) }
                .onRetryExhaustedThrow { _, rs ->  rs.failure()})
    }
```

Comment: note that although built-in `RetrySpec` and `RetryBackoffSpec` are meant to cover most of the cases, the API is _intended_ so that users can roll their own `Retry` (although when doing so they can't for now reuse bricks from the built-in specs)

Comment: Thank you, @Ckram. Unfortunately in my case delay is dynamic, coming from server.